# Resize textbox with input-group-addon to same size as textbox without addon

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form with a couple of textboxes and one of them has the class `input-group-addon` to show a € sign. Logically this takes up space but now the textbox is sticking out in the form. See the screenshot:

[image]

Here's the code for the field:

```
<div class="form-group row">
   @Html.LabelFor(m => m.EstimateAmount, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
   <div class="col-md-10">
      <div class="input-group">
         <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="mif-eur"></span>
         </span>
         @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EstimateAmount, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "" })
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here's a JSFiddle for demonstration: [**https://jsfiddle.net/7y4o4jp7/**](https://jsfiddle.net/7y4o4jp7/)

How can I fix this so that every textbox ends up the same (doesn't matter if the others shoud grow, or the one with the addon should shrink)? See below screenshot for the desired result:

[image]

Comment: try to wrap the label  <div class="col-md-2">

Comment: @Whisher the label already gets the `col-md-2` class, wrapping a div around it with that class doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Wich version of bootstrap do you have?

Comment: @SilverSurfer I'm on Bootstrap 3.3.7

Comment: If you could please make a snippet example with the relevant html please

Comment: We need to see the actual HTML that is generated, not the code that is used to create it. Please include the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can help. See [How to create a runnable code snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Sorry for this, you are right! I added a JS Fiddle link in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to apply the css max-width to the .form-group not to the input, I also would put a icon inside addon instead of keyboard € symbol:

```css
.form-group {
    max-width: 280px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="form-group row">
  <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="DossierNumber">Dossiernummer</label>
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <input class="form-control" id="DossierNumber" name="DossierNumber" placeholder="0000/0000 XXX" type="text" value="" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
  <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="Designer">Ontwerper</label>
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <input class="form-control" id="Designer" name="Designer" placeholder="" type="text" value="" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
  <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="EstimateAmount">Ramingsbedrag</label>
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eur"></i>
      </span>
      <input class="form-control" id="EstimateAmount" name="EstimateAmount" placeholder="" type="text" value="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
  <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="SubmissionStatus">Stadium van indiening</label>
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <input class="form-control" id="SubmissionStatus" name="SubmissionStatus" placeholder="" type="text" value="" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <button type="submit" id="submitButton" class="btn btn-primary">Indienen</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I have an icon in my code, but it was from another library than Bootstrap, that's why I typed the sign for demo purposes. Also, I added the `max-width` property on the `input-group` instead of the `form-group`. But your answer definitely provided me the solution! :)

Answer (score 0):

If on css . I prefere in such cases make

```
.input-group-addon {position absolute; top: 0; left: 0;}
```

and .input-group give padding-left width of your .input-group-addon + box-sizing: border-box; so padding wont expand your original size of a .input-group

Comment: I tried applying this, but it doesn't seem to make a difference. I've updated my question with a screenshot for the desired result.

Comment: oh and sure input-group position relative, be sure it have box-sizing: border-box; and max-width: 100%